# How can I prevent or handle java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException in this code?

Tags: java, indexoutofboundsexception

I am doing a telephone directory with arrays (I have to use arrays). When I try to pass an entry line that only contains surname and initials (not the number) or just surname, I want to throw an IllegalArgumentException. However, when I tried to test it I get thrown an ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException instead.

This is some of the addEntry method.

```
@Override
    public void addEntry(String line) throws IllegalArgumentException{

        int size = entries.length;

        String[] newLine = line.split("\\s+");
        String surname = newLine[0];
        String initials = newLine[1];
        String number = newLine[2];

        if (surname.length()<1 || initials.length()<1 || number.length()<1){
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Please provide a Surname, Initials and a Number");
        }


        Entry newEntry = new Entry(surname, initials, number);
```

If i try to pass to the method this entry: `arrayDirectory.addEntry("Lara   AL");`

I get this error message:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 2 out of bounds for length 2
```

pointing here: `String number = newLine[2];`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Before assigning to varirable check the length of array. Like :

```
@Override
    public void addEntry(String line) throws IllegalArgumentException{

        int size = entries.length;

        String[] newLine = line.split("\\s+");
        if(newLine.length < 3)throw new IllegalArgumentException("Please provide a Surname, Initials and a Number");
        String surname = newLine[0];
        String initials = newLine[1];
        String number = newLine[2];

        if (surname.length()< 5 || initials.length()< 5 || number.length()< 5){
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Please provide a Surname, Initials and a Number that is atleast 5 char long");
       //do other validations here like number -  is it a number or maybe has dashes and spaces

        }


        Entry newEntry = new Entry(surname, initials, number);
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you should write like that

```
String surname =  newLine.length > 0 ? newLine[0] : "";
String initials = newLine.length > 1 ? newLine[1] : "";
String number = newLine.length > 2 ? newLine[2] : "";
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is happening, because

```
String[] newLine = line.split("\\s+");
```

when

```
String line = "Lara   AL";
```

Evaluates to:

```
String[] newLine = ["Lara", "AL"];
```

And you are trying to access `newLine[2]`, when newLine only contains 2 elements.

This is happening, because `\\s+` pattern matches one or many white spaces.

To avoid this you could simply check that `newLine.size() > 2` or adjust your regex to `\\s{1}` or simply `" "`, which would enforce splitting by single white space and above would result to:

```
String[] newLine = ["Lara", " ", "AL"];
```

Answer (score 0):

If you pass "Lara   AL" as input, the `newLine` array will be initialised as

```
["Lara", "AL"]
```

and will have length 2. Instead of checking for length of surname, initials and number individually, you could just check whether the length of the array is < 3 after initialising it.

```
String[] newLine = line.split("\\s+");
if (newLine.length < 3) {
    throw new IllegalArgumentException("Please provide a Surname, Initials and a Number");
}
```